# Value of variable outside of useEffect hook has old data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

**What the code does:** It's performing a DOM search based on what's typed in an `input` (it's searching `elements` by text). All this is happening in a React component.

```
import { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
let elements: any[] = [];

const App = () => {
  const initialState = { keyEvent: {}, value: "Initial state" };
  const [state, updateState] = useReducer(
    (state: any, updates: any) => ({ ...state, ...updates }),
    initialState
  );

  function handleInputChange(event: any) {
    updateState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  function isCommand(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    return event.ctrlKey;
  }

  function handleDocumentKeyDown(event: any) {
    if (isCommand(event)) {
      updateState({ keyEvent: event });
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleDocumentKeyDown);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleDocumentKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const selectors = "button";

    const pattern = new RegExp(state.value === "" ? "^$" : state.value);

    elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selectors)).filter(
      (element) => {
        if (element.childNodes) {
          const nodeWithText = Array.from(element.childNodes).find(
            (childNode) => childNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE
          );

          if (nodeWithText) {
            // The delay won't happenn if you comment out this conditional statement:
            if (nodeWithText.textContent?.match(pattern)) {
              return element;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    );

    console.log('elements 1:', elements)
  }, [state]);

  console.log('elemets 2:', elements)

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        id="input"
        type="text"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        value={state.value}
      />
      <div id="count">{elements.length}</div>
      <button>a</button>
      <button>b</button>
      <button>c</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**The problem:** The value of `elements` outside of `useEffect` is the old data. For example, if you type `a` in the `input`, `console.log('elements 1:', elements)` will log 1, and `console.log('elements 2:', elements)` will log 0. Note: there are 3 buttons, and one of them has the text `a`.

The strange thing is that the problem doesn't happen if you comment out this if-statement:

```
// The delay won't happenn if you comment out this conditional statement:
if (nodeWithText.textContent?.match(pattern)) {
  return element;
}
```

In this case, if you type anything (since the pattern matching has been commented out), `console.log('elements 1:', elements)` and `console.log('elements 2:', elements)` will log 3. Note: there are 3 buttons.

**Question:** What could be the problem, and how to fix it? I want to render the current `length` of `elements`.

**Live code:**

[image: Edit useState same value rerender (forked)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect()` runs after your component has rendendered. So the sequence is:

1. You type something into input, that triggers `handleInputChange`
2. `handleInputChange` then updates your state using `updateState()`
3. The state update causes a rerender, so `App` is called `App()`
4. `console.log('elemets 2:', elements.length)` runs and logs `elements` as `0` as it's still empty
5. `App` returns the new JSX
6. Your `useEffect()` callback runs, updating `elements`

Notice how we're only updating the `elements` after you've rerendered and `App` has been called.

---

The state of your React app should be used to describe your UI in React. Since `elements` isn't React state, it has a chance of becoming out of sync with the UI (as you've seen), whereas using state doesn't have this issue as state updates always trigger a UI update. Consider making `elements` part of your state. If it needs to be accessible throughout your entire `App`, you can pass it down as props to children components, or use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to make it accessible throughout all your components.

With that being said, I would make the following updates:

1. Add `elements` to your state
2. Remove your `useEffect()` with the dependency of `[state]`. If we were to update the `elements` state within this effect, then that would trigger another rerender directly after the one we just did for the `state` update. This isn't efficient, and instead, we can tie the update directly to your event handler. See [You Might Not Need an Effect](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect) for more details and dealing with other types of scenarios:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
const { useEffect, useReducer} = React;

const App = () => {
  const initialState = {keyEvent: {}, value: "Initial state", elements: []};

  const [state, updateState] = useReducer(
    (state: any, updates: any) => ({ ...state, ...updates}),
    initialState
  );

  function searchDOM(value) {
    const selectors = "button";
    const pattern = new RegExp(value === "" ? "^$" : value);
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selectors)).filter(
      (element) => {
        if (element.childNodes) {
          const nodeWithText = Array.from(element.childNodes).find(
            (childNode) => childNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE
          );

          return nodeWithText?.textContent?.match(pattern);
        }
        return false;
      }
    );
  }

  function handleInputChange(event) {
    updateState({
      value: event.target.value,
      elements: searchDOM(event.target.value)
    });
  }

  function isCommand(event) {
    return event.ctrlKey;
  }

  function handleDocumentKeyDown(event) {
    if (isCommand(event)) {
      updateState({
        keyEvent: event
      });
    }
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleDocumentKeyDown);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleDocumentKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);

  console.log("elements:", state.elements.length);

  return (
    <div>
      <input id="input" type="text" onChange={handleInputChange} value={state.value} />
      <div id="count">{state.elements.length}</div>
      <button>a</button>
      <button>b</button>
      <button>c</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body).render(<App />);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is one of the best answers I've ever received. I have one question: What if I have to manipulate `elements` using `inputValue` after `updateState` runs (for example, highlighting the matched elements)? I would have to use an `useEffect` that watches `elements` and/or `inputValue`?

Comment: @alexchenco no worries :) If you need to update `elements` again, you should always be able to call `updateState({elements: <updated elements array>})`. When updating your elements array, you'd have to access `state.value` (which is your input value) that you can use to determine which elements to highlight.

Comment: I guess this code is a simplified example of your real code, but currently you're searching the DOM. If it's possible to do in your actual code, you should consider putting the things you need to search into a state/array of objects, eg: `const [btns, setBtns] = useState([{id: 0, text: "a"}, {id: 1, text: "b"}, {id: 2, text: "c"}])`, then in your JSX, use that array to render your UI, eg: `btns.map(btn => <button key={btn.id}>{btn.text}</button>`). Because you now have an array that represents your buttons, you can use `btns` in your search instead of needing to query the DOM.

Comment: For things like highlighting, you can update the objects within `btns` to represent what should be highlighted (eg: `[{id: 0, text: "a", highlighted: true}, ... ]`), and then in your `.map()` within the JSX, you'd use that `btn.highlighted` to apply a CSS class that changes your button colour for example

Comment: Where do you suggest I perform the `updateState({elements: <updated elements array>})` for the highlighting? I realized I can't do it inside `handelnputChange` because two `updateSatate` won't execute in order.

Comment: @alexchenco If I understand correctly, you should still be able to do it inside `handelnputChange` if you wanted to. Rather than setting `elements` state to the return value fo `searchDOM()` (as shown above), you can do something where you first save the returned value, such as `const foundElems = searchDOM(...);` and then do what you need to do with `foundElems` to produce your updated array (let's call that `updatedElems`). Then when you set your `elements` you can use that array:  `updateState({value: event.target.value, elements: updatedElems})`

Answer (score 3):

It's happening because of the **elements** variable is not a state, so it's not reactive.
Create a state for the elements:

```
  const [elements, setElements] = useState<HTMLButtonElement[]>([])
```

And use this state to handle the elements.

```
import { useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const initialState = { keyEvent: {}, value: "Initial state" };
  const [state, updateState] = useReducer(
    (state: any, updates: any) => ({ ...state, ...updates }),
    initialState
  );
  const [elements, setElements] = useState<HTMLButtonElement[]>([])

  function handleInputChange(event: any) {
    updateState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  function isCommand(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    return event.ctrlKey;
  }

  function handleDocumentKeyDown(event: any) {
    if (isCommand(event)) {
      updateState({ keyEvent: event });
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleDocumentKeyDown);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleDocumentKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const selectors = "button";

    const pattern = new RegExp(state.value === "" ? "^$" : state.value);

    let newElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selectors)).filter(
      (element) => {
        if (element.childNodes) {
          const nodeWithText = Array.from(element.childNodes).find(
            (childNode) => childNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE
          );

          if (nodeWithText) {
            // The delay won't happenn if you comment out this conditional statement:
            if (nodeWithText.textContent?.match(pattern)) {
              return element;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    );
    setElements(newElements)

    console.log("elements 1:", elements?.length);
  }, [state]);

  console.log("elemets 2:", elements?.length);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        id="input"
        type="text"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        value={state.value}
      />
      <div id="count">{elements?.length}</div>
      <button>a</button>
      <button>b</button>
      <button>c</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` triggered after react completed its render phase & flush the new changes to the DOM.

In your case you have two `useEffects`. The first one register your event lister which will then update your component state when input field change. This triggers a state update.( because of the setState )

So React will start render the component again & finish the cycle. And now you have 2nd useEffect which has `state` in dependency array. Since the `state` was updated & the new changes are committed to the DOM, react will execute 2nd `useEffect` logic.

Since your 2nd useEffect just assign some values to a normal variable React will not go re render your component again.

Based on your requirement you don't need a 2nd useEffect. You can use a useMemo,

```
  let elements = useMemo(() => {
    const selectors = "button";
    const pattern = new RegExp(state.value === "" ? "^$" : state.value);
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selectors)).filter(
      (element) => {
        if (element.childNodes) {
          const nodeWithText = Array.from(element.childNodes).find(
            (childNode) => childNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE
          );

          if (nodeWithText) {
            // The delay won't happenn if you comment out this conditional statement:
            if (nodeWithText.textContent?.match(pattern)) {
              return element;
            }
          }
        }
      })
  }, [state])
```

Note: You don't need to assign your `elements` into another state. It just create another unwanted re render in cycle. Since you are just doing a calculation to find out the element array you can do it with the `useMemo`